# how to find from which site, we got redirect request on iis 7

Tags: windows, iis-7, redirect

can you please tell me how to find from which we got redirect request. Is there any way to find programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the referring page.  In ASP.NET (C#):

```
string MyReferrer = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```